# Resistor or Capacitor Broke off Raspberry Pi 4 B left to the PWR text

Tags: pi-4

So my problem is that a component on my Raspberry Pi 4 B has broken off to be exact its the resistor or Capacitor of the image shown below.

My best guess is that it is simply a resistor which is part of necessary for the PWR LED but I'm not sure thought.

Also Important to note is that it still powers on and works. No idea if it works completely (all GPIO or if it gets to much voltage or something over the long term).

Edit: So my question is if someone could figure out/knows what this component is. Thanks in advance for your time.

[image]

Comment: what is your specific question? ... please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: So my question is if you know what this component is, so that I could solder it in its place. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Bits don't just fall off. The adjacent inductor is obviously also broken so you must have done something to it. If you have the bit you broke off why don't you just measure it (or replace it).

Comment: That's what I want to do thought. "Bits don't just fall off", that's only a way of speech, the actually reason is that I got of the screw while screwing it to a mounting "socket". I just want to know the part number or if it was a resistor a capacitor and if so what resistance, capacity it had. I already have the part number for the inductor from another post but thanks for the note.

Comment: The picture is unclear... could you edit the picture to ***clearly*** show which part has been knocked off?

Comment: Changed the Image sorry for the inconvenience.